# ASP.NET MVC 5 IdentityUser related entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I've the following ApplicationUser implementation :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Establishment Establishment { get; set; }
}
```

and the Establishment implementation :

```
public class Establishment
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Menu> Menus { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

An etablishment has many users but a user has only one establishment.
I want to get the current establishment by the current user id :

```
var currentUserEstablishmentId = userManager
    .FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Establishment.ID;

var establishment = db.Establishments
    .Single(e => e.ID == currentUserEstablishmentId);
```

But it throws me an error. the property Establishment of the currentUser is set to null.

How can i get the current Establishment of my current user ?

Thank you,
Regards.

Comment: You can retrieve the `Establishment` without the second query. `userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Establishment` would be enough. I don't know why it isn't working though.

Comment: @spender it does not work because lazy loading is probably not enabled and nowhere `UserManager` is configured to fetch `Establishment` object along with `user` object

Comment: @trailmax Isn't lazy loading just enabled via the virtual modifier? Think that your reciprocating ID below is a pretty hot lead though.

Comment: @spender `virtual` keyword allows only for the property to be overriden and this is mandatory for EF to be able to work - this is how it creates object proxies. Lazy loading is enabled on `DbContext` level. And yes, the answer from Andy is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding the EstablishmentID on the ApplicationUser?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual int EstablishmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Establishment Establishment { get; set; }
}
```

Then your queries become:

```
var currentUser = userManager
    .FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

var establishment = db.Establishments
    .Single(e => e.ID == currentUser.EstablishmentID);
```